# How to truncate multiple log files at once and leave only last N number of lines in it?

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, almalinux

I have two commands that I usually use to truncate log files but the issue is the first one will completely truncate it and the second one works only on one file at the time.

1. `find /path/to/log/directory -name *log -exec cp /dev/null '{}' \;`
2. `echo "$(tail -1000 /home/username/public_html/error_log)" > /home/username/public_html/error_log`

I need command that will work on multiple log files at once and truncate it so that last 1000 lines will stay in those log files.

Thanks :cheers:

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate Also note that stackoverflow is for programming questions, not Linux administration; [unix.se] may be a better fit for this question.

Answer (score 1):

A simple command for doing this should be:

```bash
for file in *.log; do [[ -f "$file" ]] && echo "$(tail -n 1000 "$file")" > "$file"; done
```

This command searches for all .log files in the current directory and truncates them by keeping only the last 1000 lines.